# SQL Consecutive records with count

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Name Calls

```
Field 1 - Phone_number
Field 2 - System_outcome

Phone_number      System_outcome  DateTime
--------------------------------------------------
07777778999       Answered        18-12-2016 17:15
07777778123       No Answer       18-12-2016 18:10
07777778999       No Answer       19-12-2016 19:30
07777778999       No Answer       19-12-2016 12:15
07777778999       No Answer       19-12-2016 13:15
07777778999       No Answer       20-12-2016 11:15
07777778124       No Answer       20-12-2016 9:15
07777778128       Answered        20-12-2016 17:15
07777778074       Answered        20-12-2016 17:15
```

Above is an example, what i need to find out is how do i find numbers that have a consecutive no answer count of more than 6?

at the moment i have been able to get the following but it's not consecutive.

```
SELECT phone_number,system_outcome,Datetime
FROM calls
WHERE DATE (datetime) BETWEEN '2016-12-23' AND '2016-12-31'
AND system_outcome = 'NO_ANSWER'
GROUP BY phone_number
HAVING count(Phone_number) > 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables to do this.

```
select phone_number from (
select c.*,
@prev_outcome:=@cur_outcome,
@cur_outcome:=system_outcome,
@prev_pnum:=@cur_pnum,
@cur_pnum:=phone_number,
case when @cur_pnum = @prev_pnum and @prev_outcome <> @cur_outcome then @rn:=@rn+1
     when @cur_pnum = @prev_pnum and @prev_outcome = @cur_outcome then @rn:=@rn
else @rn:=1 end as rank
from calls c, 
(select @rn:=0,@prev_pnum:='',@cur_pnum:='',@prev_outcome:='',@cur_outcome:='') r
order by phone_number,dt
    ) x
where system_outcome='No Answer'
group by phone_number,rank
having count(*) > 6
```

This query uses 4 variables

1) @cur_outcome which is initially set to an empty string. Thereafter the select assigns the current row's system_outcome.

2) @prev_outcome which is initially set to an empty string. Thereafter the select sets it to the @cur_outcome (which is an empty string for the first time and so on).

3) @cur_pnum which is initially set to an empty string. Thereafter the select assigns the current row's phone_number.

4) @prev_pnum which is initially set to an empty string. Thereafter the select sets it to @cur_pnum value (which is an empty string initially).

`order by` clause is important here to designate the current and previous rows based on phone_number and date.

Run the inner query initially to see how the variables are set, which would clarify things for you.

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/YASVUJ54739)

The demo contains some sample data more than what was shown in the question.

Comment: what does "select c.*" do?

Comment: where about would i specify the date? before or after the order

Comment: 1)`select c.*` selects all the columns from the table calls which is aliased as `c`.. 2) You can specify the where condition for dates in the inner query before `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use user defined variables to achieve this.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    phone_number
FROM
    (SELECT 
        phone_number,
            System_outcome,
            datetime,
            @rn:=CASE
                WHEN
                    @outcome = system_outcome
                        AND @phone = phone_number
                THEN
                    @rn + 1
                ELSE @rn:=1
            END rn,
            @outcome:=system_outcome,
            @phone:=phone_number
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        phone_number, system_outcome, Datetime
    FROM
        calls
    WHERE DATE (str_to_date(datetime,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')) BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    ORDER BY phone_number, str_to_date(datetime,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @outcome:='', @phone:='') t2) t
WHERE
    rn >= 4 AND system_outcome = 'No Answer';
```

`@rn` variable will be assigned partition-wise (partition by phone_number and system_outcome ordered by datetime) and then filter with row number and type of outcome.

Comment: Can i specifiy the date by just adding an 'and' statement at the end?

Comment: I have tried with  rn >= 2 AND system_outcome = 'No Answer' and the whole of December and nothing is showing up just the phone number field and its empty. I am 100% sure there are more than 1000 instances where consecutively a number has been labeled as no answer

Comment: Im not 100% sure but this query always gets me the correct date, WHERE DATE (timestamp_dtm) BETWEEN '2016-12-23' AND '2016-12-31'

Comment: i gave datetime as an example fyi

Comment: I am asking this because I've tested this code on my system with column datetime of type DATETIME. your column seems to be varchar. I've updated the answer. Can you try it once more?

Comment: these are my column names, phone_number, system_outcome, timestamp_dtm

Comment: Still coming up empty

Comment: It probably hidden characters in some cols or data problems, because i've tested this code with your given data and it works without any issues.

Comment: its ok i will have to try another way :(

Comment: Doesn't the other answer work for you? The one you have accepted

Comment: Iv not had a chance to run the other one, I will in a few hours

Comment: it was an accident im new to this site and how it works

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation assuming that calls are ordered in the way they come in

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  if(System_outcome ='Answered', @con:=0, @con:=@con+1) id, 
    if(Phone_number = @p, @p, @p:=Phone_number) p2,
    CASE
    WHEN Phone_number = @p THEN @con
    ELSE @con:=0 
    END unanswered_count
   ,Phone_number, System_outcome, DateTime
FROM    Table1,
   (SELECT @con:= 0) AS con,
   (SELECT @p:= -1) AS p
) agg
WHERE unanswered_count > 5
```

EDITED: some variables named wrong

Comment: @JoyиalAli I didn't test too thoroughly, but here is a quick fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f876b/1